# Facebook. Is it possible to send private messages?

Tags: php, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know that it may be stupid to post this question again because there are a lot of simmilar questions. But they are all dated 2010-2012 years and the info may be updated. Especially with new version of the facebook API V2.0 from April 30th, 2014.

I've made some digging on the possible options and found [Chat API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/) and interesting post related to it: http://nishgtm.com/2013/11/facebook-message-api-php/

But I couldn't make it work.

Also there some info on new Message Dialog thing on the FB docs but there are only [iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/message-dialog) and [Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/message-dialog) examples.

I'm building a web application and a mobile application. And I wonder, is it possible to send private messages on the behalf of the fb application, not fb user.

Comment: Also I think that notifications would do the job for me. But I still can't find any relevant info on their implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to send messages on behalf of the application.

To let people that use your app send to their friends, use:

1. iOS: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/message-dialog/
2. Android: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/message-dialog/
3. desktop web: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog
4. mobile web: unfortunately, this isn't supported yet

Answer (score 1):

It's 2017 and I found something interesting. We can send private messages on mobile now, but it's buried. Facebook decided to allow sending private messages to the [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) where the user has to click the dropdown and select **"Share in a private message"**. This works on all platforms and I attached a screenshot below. I hope this helps someone in the future until Facebook decides to change things again.

[image: Facebook Share Dialog Options]

Comment: It doesn't seem to work if you attach some text to the link

Answer (score 0):

Read about

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications

this may be what you need